# Getting Error 402 while publishing package using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using npm version 2.15.11 and node version 4.7.2 on ubuntu 14.04. I want to publish my packages. when i use the command:

npm publish

i am geting the error: You need a paid account to perform this action. For more info, visit: https://www.npmjs.com/private-modules

Below is the screenshot of error:
[image]

Please provide me the solution to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 153):

Run

```
npm publish --access=public
```

the first time you publish a scoped package.

The default access setting is private, but for this you need a paid account. Hence the error message.

Answer (score 41):

In addition to the command line option provided by [bersling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862841/12702232), you can merge the following into your `package.json`:

```
{
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  }
}
```

[Reference in npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#publishconfig). Useful when you want to template it into your package manifests and not think about it.

P.S. had one of those old OpenId accounts, forgot to update it before it was nuked, no longer have the ability to add this as a comment to bersling's reply, which is where I feel this really belongs.

Answer (score 12):

In `package.json`, npm version 6+ you have this option:

```
"private": true/false,
```

Be sure is false, and also try to use this flag:

```
npm publish --access=public
```

Answer (score 2):

you probably initialized your package with a scope so that it is private. Read
https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro

Comment: I am using the command:
    npm publish --access public

and again i am getting the error:
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 403
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-92-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "publish" "--access" "public"
npm ERR! node v4.7.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code E403

npm ERR! Forbidden : @incar/wise-car
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

Comment: you need to make sure that your npm init is not private.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add that, if you tried all the other answers and still get this error, someone(maybe yourself) could have somehow changed the package to private previously, in which case, you need to set the package to public before you could publish again... Orz