# why I am unable to publish my package to npmjs

Tags: node.js, npm, publish

I have created an account with npmjs.com also I'm following the how-to-npm tutorial from command line (linux). I'm at the stage where I should publish my test module. But I keep getting error:

```
You must sign up for private packages : @zentech/node
```

these are all the error when npm publish

```
npm ERR! publish Failed PUT 402
npm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-33-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "publish"
npm ERR! node v4.7.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code E402

npm ERR! You must sign up for private packages : @zentech/node
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/george/node/npm-debug.log
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "@zentech/node",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node test.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "repository": "http://github.com/zentech/node"
}
```

does anyone know why the error? thanks

Comment: What about the error is unclear? It looks like you haven't signed up for private packages. If you want to use private packages you have to sign up for it.

Comment: chech this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981686/getting-error-402-while-publishing-package-using-npm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Error 402 while publishing package using npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981686/getting-error-402-while-publishing-package-using-npm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> You must sign up for private packages: @zentech/node

So you either sign up, or you change the name of your package from `@zentech/node` to a public name, like `zentech-node`.

Comment: I'm trying to publish a public package (this is first time with node) so all the errors are unfamiliar. do I need to rename my package to zentech-node?

Comment: @miatech what was the solution?

Comment: `npm publish --access=public`

Answer (score 25):

As suggested in the comments above the way to  publish a scoped package i.e.

```
@scope/my-package
```

is to use the --access flag when publishing

```
npm publish --access=public
```

You **do not** need to sign up for private packages unless you actually want your package to be private.

Comment: or    yarn  publish --access=public

Answer (score 8):

Or you can set the public access on `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "publishConfig": {"access": "public"}
  ...
}
```

rather than:

```
{
  ...
  "publishConfig": {"access": "restricted"}
  ...
}
```