# Still getting 402 when publishing to private after upgrading plan using NPM

Tags: npm

I was getting the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981686/getting-error-402-while-publishing-package-using-npm) but I DID want to make it private so I upgraded my account. I regen a new Auth token with publishing rights and tried to publish again, however, I still got the previous 402 error...

> 402 Payment Required - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@jrg%2fsimple-ui - You must sign up for private packages

I have other public repos I have published to in the past with no problems under the `@jrg` org. My .npmrc file looks like this...

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=...
```

What am I missing why am I still getting a 402?

Comment: I also tried using npm login with the same issues

Answer (score 0):

I had previously posted to the `jrg` scope but only public repos. When I signed up for the individual account I can only deploy to the scope that matches my username. AFAIK there is no way to configure this so the other scope can be mapped to the indv.